# Доступ к списку объектов из ObservableArrayList с потока

Tags: javafx, потоки-данных, коллекции

Необходимо реализовать заполнение choiceBox данными преподавателей. Преподаватели хранятся в классе Data:

```
public class Data{
 private static final ObservableList<Teacher> teachersData = 
 FXCollections.observableArrayList();

 public static ObservableList<Teacher> getTeachersData() {
     return teachersData;
 }
}
```

В другом классе необходимо в choiceBox положить имена преподавателей, реализовал заполнение таким образом:

```
public class LoadCreateDialogController {

@FXML
private ChoiceBox teacherBox;


public void setLoad() {

    ObservableList<String> teachersList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Data.getTeachersData().stream().findAny().get().getFullName());
    teacherBox.setItems(teachersList);
}
```

Проблема в том, что в коробку кладётся только первый из ObservableArrayList преподаватель, как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findAny` возвращает `Optional` с каким-то из значений внутри стрима, если же вам надо все имена то код должен быть примерно таким `FXCollections.observableArrayList(Data.getTeachersData().stream().map(Teacher::getFullName).collect(Collectors.toList));` (Хотя по хорошему стоит сделать свой `Collector` который будет собирать сразу в `ObservableList`, но код для него я на память не напишу).